# Is there a way to ignore a hasMany relationship when using dynamic finders?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, dynamic-finders

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    String name
}

class Book {
    static hasMany = [chapters: Chapter]
    String title
}

class Chapter {
     String chapter
}
```

If I am trying to find all authors `Author.findAll()` , is there a way to ignore the chapter relationships that are being pulled into memory as well?

Comment: log the query to see how many queries are generated. In GORM, associations are by default lazily loaded. That means, relationships are not queried until they are referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> f I am trying to find all authors Author.findAll() , is there a way to
>   ignore the chapter relationships that are being pulled into memory as
>   well?

Yes.  That is what will happen by default.  With the domain classes authored exactly as you have shown there `Author.findAll()` will generate SQL like this (the exact syntax may be different depending on what dialect you are using, this is what will be generated for H2):

```
select author0_.id as id1_0_, author0_.version as version2_0_, author0_.name as name3_0_ from author author0_
```

If you start interacting with the `Author` instances and reference the `books` property and that will trigger more sql being sent to the database.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The reason is because the mapping option `lazy` is configured by default as true. See here: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html

Comment: @ricardogobbo Right.  I am pretty sure we always had that setup to default to `true`.  If we changed it that might have been way back in 1.x days but I am pretty sure it was always that way.